# Regular Expression not containing a specific string

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I'm trying to build a event tracking based goal conversion within Google Analytics. I'm trying to build a regular expression which matches all event labels except these strings:

`https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instagram.android`
`https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8`

I'm trying this:

```
.*((?!play\.google\.com).).*|.*((?!itunes\.apple\.com).).*
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps you should think of it the other way around - look for those strings so you can ignore them, then parse all the rest.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: it's indeed the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your code like below,

```
^(?!.*?(?:play\.google\.com|itunes\.apple\.com)).*
```

I assume that you're trying to check the above string against url strings only.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jN7uC0/2)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a negative lookahead to avoid the lines that you won't catch, adding a group (or named group) at the end of the regex

```
^(?!https?:\/\/(?:play\.google|itunes.apple).com)(.+)
```

[Try it!](https://regex101.com/r/xOzK13/1)

Named group version

```
^(?!https?:\/\/(?:play\.google|itunes.apple).com)(?<eventLabel>.+)
```

[Try it!](https://regex101.com/r/xOzK13/2)